# What iOs version apps are accepted in App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

My app is currently in version 3.2.3. What version of iOs apps are currently being accepted by Apple. Links?

Comment: Am I reading your question wrongly? Any version number you can think of can be specified for your app; Apple doesn't care about your app's versioning scheme. Do you mean to ask which versions of iOS Apple requires your app to support or iOS SDK you need to build against?

Comment: @Bolt: methinks he's referring to the iOS version he's building against.

Comment: yes iOs version? what version I think it is 4.0 but I could not find any documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that Apple would ensure backwards compatibility with their API layers.  This means that 4.0 can run any App down through 1.0, but 3.2 can't run an app from 3.6 if there is code being used not available to that system.

Therefore, you should be in the clear.

Comment: Thanks! I just checked and I have 3.2 and 4.0 versions. When I test my iPhone app it says "Simulator - 4.0" and "Device - 4.0" which means I am okay.

Comment: You can only submit from iPhone OS 3.X onwards now I think.

Answer (score 6):

Apple is no longer accepting the submission of apps that are compatible (by declaration in the Deployment Target Build Setting) with an iPhone OS earlier/lower than 3.0.  You can strictly use only 2.0 compatible APIs, but the Deployment Target setting will keep that app from being installed on a 2.0 device anyway.

Anything from 3.0 to 4.1 for iPhone/iOS Deployment Target and 3.2 to 4.1 for iOS Base SDK appears to be the range currently accepted.

Comment: This is actually a more correct answer to the question... (at this time.) (upvoted)

Answer (score 0):

Apple requires you to link against the iOS 4.0 or 4.1 SDK for iPhone apps, and iOS 3.2 SDK for iPad ones. However, you may still target 3.x iOS devices by setting the 'iOS Deployment target' in the Target Info window to an older version, with 3.0 being the oldest that will be accepted by Apple.

For instance, my company recently released an iPhone game that was built against the iOS 4.1 SDK but had its iOS deployment target set to 3.0. This way all iOS 3.0 devices can run the app.