# Can I make iPhone apps with these specs?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I have Xcode version 3.1.3 and OS X version 10.5.8.

What is the minimum iOS version for iPhone apps that Apple will accept into the App Store and can I develop for it without spending any more money (i.e. with what I've currently got or via free upgrade)?

Can I develop a universal app for iPad with these specs as well?

What version of the SDK do I need so that the app runs on the latest iOS versions as well as the oldest acceptable versions (my current one seems to have deployment options up to iOS 3.0)?

Thanks for any help, I used to develop apps prolifically but have been out of the game for over a year and things seem to have changed a fair bit.

Comment: Isn't upgrading to XCode 4 a free upgrade if you are a paid developer? Also, I wouldn't say things have changed that much in a year.

Comment: you need the latest (or nearly) os and xcode - and this will be enforced by Apple and required by the systems you want to develop for.

Comment: @Alastair, they're free, but not for the hackintosh crowd (free in price, but not free in effort). And I'd venture that Ahab is of that persuasion, otherwise he probably wouldn't ask the question.

Comment: @Alastair - Xcode is free, but Snow Leopard isn't, and Xcode 3.2 or 4 both require SL.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 4 is a freely available for all members of the iOS and Mac Developer Programs. Xcode 4 can also be bought trough the App Store for 3.99 euro. Xcode 3 is freely available.

Only 'iPhone Developer Program' members can run applications on their device or submit applications to the App Stores. Joining the program costs 99 dollar. Otherwise you can only run applications on the iPhone Simulator and distribute applications through Cydia.

Compatibility:
[What iOs version apps are accepted in App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697216/what-ios-version-apps-are-accepted-in-app-store)

Note:
*You can actually distribute applications without paying 99 dollar, but only to Jailbroken (Cydia).*